# Qt query execution error

Tags: qt, qtsql

```
bool    MainWindow::initDb() {
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); // defined on class header as QSqldatabase db
    db.setDatabaseName("data.db");
    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,
                              tr("Error"),
                              tr("Could not save data. Database problem."));
        return false;
    }
    query.prepare("create table if not exists snippet (id int primary key, title varchar(255) not null, tags varchar(255), snippet text)");
    if (!query.exec()) { // error
        QMessageBox::critical(this,
                              tr("Database error"),
                              tr("Could not setup database"));
        qDebug() << "Database error : " << query.lastError();
        return false;
    }
    query.clear();
    return true;
}
```

Database It shows **Database error** message box and the following in the console.

```
Database error :  QSqlError(-1, "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

Comment: What platform is this? Do you have sqlite and the sqlite qt plugin installed?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 11.10, SQLIte installed. Even works fine if I use query as a local object. Just because when **query** is in class property problem arise.

Comment: If it is a class member the default constructor is used: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-2. Try instantiating passing the correct database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a partial solution. Making **query** as local object with passing **db** to it's constructor solve the problem.
Like

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
```